# Convert MS Excel CEILING formula to PHP

Tags: php, excel

I'm finding it really hard to match the values properly.

I have a Excel formula e.g.

```
=CEILING(8/2,0.5)
```

How do I convert it into PHP. I have tried the following function from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php#85430) but doesn't work properly

```
function ceiling($number, $significance = 1){
    return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
}
```

I have also tried the [Ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function. Same as above, doesn't work properly. I values are mismatched compare to Excel.

Comment: Do you have an example of when it doesn't work (input, expected output, and actual output)?

Comment: In the link you provided try the function "roundup" provided by steve_phpnet.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  Not sure if it takes much explanation...it just calculates the $multiple and rounds up one integer from there and multiplies by the number parameter.  That will mimic Excel's ceiling function.

```
function ceiling($number, $significance){
  $multiple   = $number / $significance;
  $remainder  = $number % $significance;

  if($remainder == 0){
    $result = $number;
  }else{
    $result = ceil($multiple) * $significance;
  }
  echo "\nceiling($number, $significance)";
  echo "\nmultiple = $multiple";
  echo "\nremainder = $remainder";
  echo "\nresult = $result\n";

  return $result;
}
```